React Typescript webpack unix build error
i have react webpack typescript project, when i build on windows it`s all ok, but when i push to git, cicd cant build it, show error
ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 5:51
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:51)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import App from "./App";
| 
> createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />);

webpack.config.ts
import path from "path";
import { Configuration, DefinePlugin } from "webpack";
import "webpack-dev-server";
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from "html-webpack-plugin";

const webpackConfig = (): Configuration => ({
    entry: [path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx")],
    devtool: "eval-source-map",
    stats: "errors-warnings",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: "[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                },
                exclude: /(node_modules|\.webpack|build)/,
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        alias: {
            "@assets": path.resolve(__dirname, "assets"),
            "@src": path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        },
        plugins: [],
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        open: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
            inject: true,
        }),
        // DefinePlugin allows you to create global constants which can be configured at compile time
        new DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": process.env.production || !process.env.development,
        })
    ],
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'initial',
        },
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
});

export default webpackConfig;

tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "build",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ES6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "node_modules/*"
            ],
            "@assets/*": [
                "./assets/*"
            ],
            "@src/*": [
                "./src/*"
            ]
        },
        "lib": [
            "esnext",
            "dom",
            "dom.iterable"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "ts-node": {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "module": "CommonJS"
        }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build"
    ],
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "fe",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --mode=development --env development --open --hot",
    "build:testing": "webpack --mode=development --env testing --progress",
    "build:staging": "webpack --mode=production --env staging --progress",
    "build:production": "webpack --mode=production --env production --progress",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --quiet --fix"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@fontsource/montserrat": "^5.0.17",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.15",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.15",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "sort-by": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.79",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.25",
    "@types/webpack": "^5.28.5",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4"
  }
}

index.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(<App />);

i can build on windows, localy, but on unix cicd i ahve error
version node 20.9.0
npm 10
on windows and unix some versions
